# d3 v4 zoom gap when not in `zoom mode`

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to implement regular zoom on my project, with switching mode: brush mode and zoom mode.

The Problem:
When scrolling (by mouse) when on brush mode, its changing the `k` value on d3, so after switching (by pressing `Z`) to zoom mode, d3 takes the changed `k` value and throwing my svg to that position.

How can I make d3 save current position static while not in zoom mode?

Follow the steps to recreate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/chryaner/wuLuLtyy/

[image]

Edit: moved the code from snippet to jsfiddle